# Persisting object controller details

Tags: ember.js

I have the following template setup displaying a list of items, and wrapping each list in its own controller:

```
{{#each controller itemController="contact"}}
  <div class="contact-entry">
    <div class="title" {{action toggle on="click"}}>{{title}}</div>
    {{#if showDetails}}
    <div class="details">
      <div>{{safe details}}</div>
    </div>
    {{/if}}
  </div>
{{/each}}
```

The main controller is an ArrayController called `ContentsController`, and each item is wrapped in an ObjectController called `ContentController`. The content of the `ContentsController` is set explicitly in the route (I've simplified the data):

```
App.ContactsRoute = Em.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
   return [{'title': 'first'}, {'title': 'second'}];
  }
});
```

This works really well. However if I navigate to another path and then back again, the settings on the `ContentController` don't persist. What happens is that the model data gets reloaded, and I assume a ObjectController gets created for each of the list items. Incidentally this is not the case for the `ContentsController`, which keeps its settings.

What is the solution to preventing ember of creating new `ContentController` for every list item every time I access the page?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your reference to `ContentController` is really `ContactsController` since you are using `itemController="contact"` in your #each block.

What kind of data are you trying to persist? The `showDetails` flag? The `ContactControllers` are going be created and destroyed anytime you exit / enter the route and there isn't anyway I know of to keep those around.

The `ContactsController` keeps its properties because its a singleton controller generated because you have a `ContactsRoute`.

Comment: Then how do I get the contactController to persist. What do I need to change to get it to work?